# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'OptimizeResult' and 'float'

Tags: python-3.x

I have written this code to find an optimum angle of attack for an aerofoil to get a desired lift but not sure what the error is. Vortex_panel is a function given to me by my uni.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def find_alpha(target_cl, points, guess):

    def fixed_lift(alpha, points, target_cl):
        [cl,cp,xc,yc,dy,ds,theta,vt] = vortex_panel(points,alpha,0)
        f = (target_cl - cl)**2
        return f

    alpha_limits = ((0,90),)
    alpha = minimize(fixed_lift, guess, options={'eps':0.025}, bounds =alpha_limits, args = (points, target_cl))                                                 

    [cl,cp,xc,yc,dy,ds,theta,vt] = vortex_panel(points,alpha,0)
    return alpha, cl

target_cl  =(0.7746 / (0.9 * 0.4)) /0.92
u2 = 0.5
guess = 5
points = parametric_aerofoil2(u2)
[alpha, cl] = find_alpha(target_cl, points, guess)
print(target_cl, alpha, cl)
```

When I run it this error gets raised.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-ac6f6a05eabb> in <module>()
      3 guess = 5
      4 points = parametric_aerofoil2(u2)
----> 5 [alpha, cl] = find_alpha(target_cl, points, guess)
      6 print(target_cl, alpha, cl)

<ipython-input-34-d30e5083ae57> in find_alpha(target_cl, points, guess)
      7     alpha_limits = ((0,90),)
      8     alpha = minimize(fixed_lift, guess, options={'eps':0.025},     bounds = alpha_limits, args = (points, target_cl))
----> 9     [cl,cp,xc,yc,dy,ds,theta,vt] = vortex_panel(points,alpha,0)
     10     return alpha, cl

~/Documents/Aerodynamic Wing Design/Code/aclabtools.py in     vortex_panel(pointsDef, alpha_deg, plot)
     62     psi=np.zeros((npanel+1))
     63     U=1;
---> 64     alpha=alpha_deg*np.pi/180.0;
     65     for i in range(0,npanel):
     66         xc[i]=(xb[i]+xb[i+1])/2.0

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'OptimizeResult' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive solved the problem now. It was a problem with me not knowing fully how the function given to me by my Uni worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the interpreter is trying to multiply two objects and they are not the same datatype. Python is a strong typing PL, that is to say that **datatypes must be the same** in order to perform such operation.

Comment: Please, provide all the methods for a debugging process. Thank you.

Comment: I've added it thanks for help. I know the error is because of two different datatypes that can't multiply but I'm not sure what the solution to the problem would be